# Document.write function replaces the whole page with the text

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I am relatively new to javascript and I created a function to multiply two numbers together, but `document.write` replaces the whole page with the answer. I know this is what `document.write` is supposed to do, but just wanted an alternative. Remember, I am new to the language, so if it's possible, try to explain the answer. Thanks!

```
<script language="javascript">
    function calculate(){
        var number1= document.getElementById("num1"); 
        var number2= document.getElementById("num2");
        var answer=number1.value * number2.value;
        document.write(answer);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: that's what it's supposed to do if you don't do it during parsing

Comment: @Markasoftware - Yes, and the question explicitly says that that is what it is supposed to do, and asks for an alternative...

Comment: whoops! didn't read the whole question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already know how to use `document.getElementById()` to retrieve the values of inputs on your page. So do something similar to update an element that holds the answer:

```
<div id="answer"></div>
```

...and then:

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answer;
```

Simle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V5R5h/1/

Comment: or he/she could do it during parsing somehow

Comment: @Markasoftware - The values are coming from form fields (input elements, I imagine), and so presumably are entered by the user after the page loads.

Answer (score 2):

If you add an empty element like `<span id="fillme"></span>` to the document you can use this with `var fillme = document.getElementById("fillme");` and then later assign content to `fillme` with `fillme.innerHTML = answer;`